# How to render RABL template with status code Rails +3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

I want to render my rabl template, but want to be sure it renders the proper http status code. For example, creating a user, should render a 201.

users_controller.rb

```
@user = a_user

render 'users/create'
```

create.json.rabl

```
object @user
attributes :id, :blah, :blah2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
respond_with @user
```

rails will use the appropriate status code

Comment: right on, i'll try that. what if you are not using respond_with?

Comment: render 'users/create', status: 201